How can I connect to Horizon ADAM LDAP Database with PowerShell or other cli?
I am trying to automate some repetitive tasks in VMware Horizon.
In particular I need a way to modify the  ADAM LDAP Database with something different of adsiedit so that the change can happen on bulck. Need to change the attribute pae-VmDeletePolicy from “DeleteOnUse”  to “Never” and back to "DeleteOnUse" for a list of 100+ pools.
I searched everyware but cannot find how to connect with powershell to this ldap database .
I got only the official way https://kb.omnissa.com/s/article/2012377 which involves adsiedit.
Did someone knows how this can be done?

Many Thanks!
